# When I try to install a snap, it gets stuck on the installation of core

Tags: software-installation, snap

I am running Ubuntu 16.10, and this is what happens when I do `sudo snap install libreoffice`:

```
Run configure hook of "core" snap if present
```

And it keeps doing this indefinitely. Any way to solve this?

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the output of `snap list | grep core`

Comment: Do you still get this bug on Ubuntu 17.04 (and with `snapd` 2.28)?